# Difference between "/opt/google/chrome/chrome" and "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" on Fedora 22

Tags: google-chrome, fedora

I was looking into how to open up Google Chrome through the terminal on Fedora 22, and I found two executable files that both seem to launch Google Chrome; `chrome` and `google-chrome`.

- `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`
- `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

Is there a functional difference between the two files?

Answer (score 3):

While they are both executable `/opt/google/chrome/chrome` is the actual binary and `/opt/google/chome/google-chrome` is a wrapper for the binary that you could use to alter some options for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fedora machine here, so I can't test that.

First: Did you add a repo or how did you install Chrome on Fedora?
Make sure you do not actually have to Chromes installed.

Then: look at both executables. Chances are, one of them is a symlink or just a bash script to launch the other.

Also see what gets launched when you launch from terminal:
`which chrome`

Also you might wanna look at the .desktop files of google chrome in:
`/usr/share/applications`, specifically the `Exec` part.